# Ethereum wallet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, cryptocurrency, geth

I'm new to Ethereum and for learning purposes, I want to mine. The Ethereum wallet main network sync just finished but I can't see the button "start mining (shift+command+m)" (appears on the solo network) won't appear here.

Why is that?

what should I do?

OS & Version: MacOSX Sierra
Node version: geth 1.8.10
Number of blocks synchronized: 5 738 096

Development in main network:

[image: Development in main network]

Development in Solo network:

[image: Development in Solo network]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are running a light client.  The light client is only meant to provide users with low capacity assurance about information on the blockchain. 
It doesn't have the capabilities to mine, in fact, it can only process about 1KB of data per 2 minutes.  Its mainly used to gather information and personal account uses.  You should look into running the full client/node

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol
https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/getting_a_client.html